# How to deploy, Ola Hallengren's Index Maintenance Script on RDS SQL Server Agent?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-rds

New to cloud (new project, starting yesterday) and have questions on AWS RDS SQL Server Instance. Since, I can't install Ola Hallengren script (I only need the IndexOptimize for updates statistics) on master or msdb database. What are the other ways to do this? Cause in on-prem setup, I just install these scripts on master database but on cloud I cannot do this.

Need advice the from the experts.

Comment: You could create the proc temporarily inside a user database, then execute it and delete after execution.

Comment: @DenisRubashkin, thanks for the inputs. Already tried on a test RDS instance and it's working fine.